# python group by with sum and count at the same time not working

Tags: python, count, sum, grouping

I have a list of dicts that need to be grouped by, and I need to do count and sum at the same time.
Count as how many times this dictionary appears for worker in my case and 
SUM for what is the sum field for one key based on worker 
I can do one at the time but not both.

this is my code

```
grouper = lambda x: (x["rw_worker_nick"], x["rw_date"].replace(day=1))
vacation_group = []
for key, grp in groupby(sorted(vacation, key = grouper), grouper):
    temp_dict = dict(zip(["rw_worker_nick", "rw_date"], key))
    temp_dict['vac_days'] = len(list(grp))
    temp_dict['vac_duration'] = sum(item["rw_duration"] for item in grp)
    vacation_group.append(temp_dict)
```

The sum always returns 0

any suggestions ??

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't iterate over the iterables that `groupby` produces more than once. `list(grp)` consumed all items from the iterable.

Store the list first, then take the length and the sum from that:

```
for key, grp in groupby(sorted(vacation, key = grouper), grouper):
    temp_dict = dict(zip(["rw_worker_nick", "rw_date"], key))
    grp = list(grp))
    temp_dict['vac_days'] = len(grp)
    temp_dict['vac_duration'] = sum(item["rw_duration"] for item in grp)
    vacation_group.append(temp_dict)
```